# What does ^= mean in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, syntax, operators

I have the following line of code:

```
contents[pos++] ^= key[shift++];
```

What does operator `^=` mean?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It is the [XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) assignment operator. Basically:

```
x ^= y;
```

is the same as:

```
x = x ^ y;
```

Comment: This, of course, assumes the `^=` operator hasn't been overloaded to who knows what. :-)

Comment: Also you should point out that its not just part of the C[++] language  but its within many languages.

Answer (score 13):

This means preform an [XOR operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR) on `contents[pos++]` using `key[shift++]` and set `contents[pos++]` equal to the result.

Example:

```
contents[pos++]     00010101
key[shift++]        10010001
                    --------
                    10000100
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a bitwise XOR operator.

```
x ^= y
```

is basically

```
x = x ^ y
```

of course, this is a bitwise operation

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

Answer (score 0):

It is a bitwise exclusive OR on two integers. http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/726626-what-caret-qualifier

Comment: But specifically, it assigns the result of the XOR back to the left-hand argument.